# Strategy to deploy versioned assets (for PHP app's assets to Amazon S3)

Tags: php, amazon-s3, web-deployment

I currently deploy a PHP app's static assets using [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd).

If an asset for Amazon S3 has changed (like a JavaScript script), I'll rename it manually, so that the new version is synced and served by Amazon Cloudfront.

Are there documented practices for deploying a PHP app's static assets to Amazon S3? I've seen that sites use a hash to refer to a certain deployment version of their assets. I'm wondering the approach to get that hash (like the git commit SHA?) to be referenced by the web application.

The approach I could see working is writing to a stand-alone config file that holds the current SHA, and read from it for deployment.

**Update 1 with current process**

I'm looking to make the deployment of assets more automated:

- Make a change to the app's JavaScript
- Rename the script from `app.23.js` to `app.24.js`
- Edit the site's header HTML template to refer to `app.24.js`
- Commit all change to git
- Merge the `develop` branch into `master`
- Tag the commit with a new version number
- Push code to BitBucket
- Use s3cmd to syncronise the new script to Amazon S3 (and therefore Cloudfront CDN)
- SSH into server, and pull the latest git tree. The production server serves the `master` branch.

Comment: Can you shed some more light on your workflow that you have mentioned. I am unable to piece it together to suggest a solution :(.

Comment: @NomanUrRehman Thanks, I've updated it with "Update 1".

Comment: Laravel 5 has a good solution with Laravel Elixer: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/10#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to think there is no specific answer to this question but here are a few things.

1. If you only want to automate the manual work you are doing then it might be worthwhile to look into a few deployment tools. Capistrano and Magallanes are two names that come to my mind but you can google for this and I am sure you will find a lot of options.
2. The Rails framework was built on the philosophy that there is a best way to do things. It also uses hashes to version static assets and does its thing out of the box on the fly. You can look into implementing hashing in your case.
3. Grunt is another automation tool that you can look into. I found this module that might come in handy https://github.com/theasta/grunt-assets-versioning

I would say for me, the 2,3,4 are the problem areas in your workflow. Renaming manually and updating code every time does not sound too nice. As you have pointed out, GIT hashes are unique so perhaps append the GIT hash to your assets during deployment and sync them to S3/Cloudfront ?

Comment: Thaks for the pointers. It looks like the Rails community have addressed this point. Here is a related Grunt article related to PHP too.

Comment: Apologies, it looks like my link isn't being accepted.